# Change <item> node class via di.xml

Tags: magento2, di, items, virtualtype

If I have something like this:

```
<type name="Magento\Downloadable\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Composite">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="downloadablePanel" xsi:type="string">Magento\Downloadable\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\DownloadablePanel</item>
            <item name="links" xsi:type="string">Magento\Downloadable\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Links</item>
            <item name="samples" xsi:type="string">Magento\Downloadable\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Samples</item>
            <item name="usedDefault" xsi:type="string">Magento\Downloadable\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\UsedDefault</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

and I want to change one of these classes in `<item>` nodes. Is it possible via `di.xml`?

I have used `<preference>` and it worked, but I don't feel as it is best solution. Of course for public methods `plugin` should work. What in case of `protected` or `private` method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's say you want to change the `links` one.
You have to create your own module that depends on the `Magento_Downloadable` module and add this in the `di.xml` of your module.

```
<type name="Magento\Downloadable\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Composite">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="links" xsi:type="string">Your\ClassName\Goes\Here</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Just keep in mind that if the code you posted is from `frontend/di.xml` you have to add the new code in `frontend/di.xml`. Same goes for `adminhtml/di.xml`

Comment: If plugin is possible for such a class I bet it's better to use plugin over changing item class via xml, isn't it?

Comment: yes, you can do that, but from the question I understood that you want to completely replace one of the items.

Comment: actually I want to override method which is `protected` so we can exclude for this case `plugins`. Comment just in sake of complecity if somone would read it and find it helpful :)

Comment: What in case virtualType? For example:
`<virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="downloadable" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Downloadable\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Composite</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>`

Comment: create a new virtual type and use that one. ot you can simply use a real class.

Comment: @lord_of_strings, you dont need to override protected methods in Links class. You need to modify product form component data or metadata. There is nice functionality of Magento\Ui\DataProvider\Modifier\Pool, integrated to product form component. I think, that you need to use custom modifier after Downloadable modifier and rewrite needed data in array.

Comment: @Max Stsepantsevich actually I think there is even more lightweight way. i can modify method `modifyMeta` which uses method I want to override, by `aroundMethod`. I can just order different behavior, in different cases.